# Selenium Java: I am automating a retail site.In Product landing page, we have list of products and associated price and buttons

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

[image]For every product we have 2 buttons. At any point only one button would be present.

Example:

Prod 1     No Price             button1

Prod 2     Price                button1
                                button2

I need to click on a product with button 2 and price available. Please provide a solution on how to traverse through the products and click on the related buttons.

```
    List<WebElement> Prod = driver.findElements(ProdDesc);
    List<WebElement> price = driver.findElements(prodPrice);
    List<WebElement> btn = driver.findElements(Button2);

    for (int i = 0;i<Prod.size();i++){
    if(price.get(i).isDisplayed())
    {
        if(btn .get(i).isDisplayed())
        {
        Prod.get(i).click();
        break;
        }
    }
    }
```

The above code identifies the button and price which is available on the second product but clicks on the first one.

Comment: If it is a second button you need to click, you should check if there at least two buttons, then—if so—choose the second one and click it. In your current code, you have `btn.get(i)` and `i` depends on amount of products on page.

Comment: I am getting it. let me put it this way. prod(0) does not contain 2 buttons. prod(1) has 2 buttons. So instead of traversing the pdts, I need to look for the buttons right?

Comment: It would be so if you needed only to click the button. But you also need to have price displayed, which is I believe is outside the button element and inside the product element.

Comment: could you share the relevant xml code? If you create a xpath with all conditions you will have directly the nodes to click.

Comment: I am sorry. I am not allowed to share the content .Please refer question for dom .

Comment: @testergirl added an answer. It's pseudocode, but the idea is simple and much alike what you've already done, with one difference - you need to fetch price and button elements from inside product element.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Find list of available products */
List<WebElement> products = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(PRODUCT_CSS);

/* Traverse the list */
for (int i = 0; i < products.size(); i++) {

  /* Get the price of a product, might throw an exception if price is absent */
  WebElement price = products.get(i).findElement(By.cssSelector(PRICE_CSS);

  if (price.isDisplayed()) {
    /* Get the list of buttons inside the product element */
    List <WebElement> btnList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(BTN_CSS));

    /* Make sure there are two buttons */  
    if (btnList.size() == 2 && btnList.get(1).isClickable()) {
      /* Click the second button */
      btnList.get(1).click()
    }
  }
}
```